# shuffle a sprite group

Tags: sprites, python, pygame

Is there a way to shufle a group of sprites created with:

```
pygame.sprite.Group()
```

I have tried using random.shuffle but it apparently doesn't work on sprite groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since groups are an iterator, you can use:

```
sprs = list(spr_group)
random.shuffle(sprs)
```

You should not rely on Python's hashing order to randomize sprites for you. It is not a good RNG.

Answer (score 0):

According to pygame documentation:

> The Sprites in the Group are not ordered, so drawing and iterating the Sprites is in no particular order. 
>   http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group

I think the best you can do is not to use the Group, and make your own group mechanism.
If you need only ordered update then use http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates

Comment: Thanks, I will keep the sprite group though. Your first sentence is correct, each time I create/empty/create the group it comes back in a different order, which is just what I need.

Comment: -1. If you desperately need the _group_ to shuffle you can simply subclass `Group`, you don't need to avoid it. But you probably don't want the group per se to be shuffled; you just want a shuffled copy of the sprites in the group.

Answer (score 0):

As other already said, the `sprite.Group` iterator yield its members in an unordered way (like a `dict`, not like a a `list`).

So if you're after a simple unordered list (not properly shuffled with a random method - if you want that follow [user744's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/11858/77318)), just get what it gives by default.

The "problem" here is quite the contrary: [how to get an ordered list of sprites from it (or a sprite by its index in the group)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11838/sprite-group-doesnt-support-indexing)